# How to log the errors both stdout and sterr files in the HTCondor HPC manager?

Tags: hpc, condor, htcondor

I want to log the errors to both stderr and stdout, how does one do this?

This is my current script:

```
####################
#
# Experiments script
# Simple HTCondor submit description file
#
# reference: https://gitlab.engr.illinois.edu/Vision/vision-gpu-servers/-/wikis/HTCondor-user-guide#submit-jobs
#
# chmod a+x ~/diversity-for-predictive-success-of-meta-learning/main.sh
# chmod a+x /shared/rsaas/miranda9//diversity-for-predictive-success-of-meta-learning/main.sh
# condor_submit -i
# condor_submit job.sub
#
####################

Executable = /home/miranda9/diversity-for-predictive-success-of-meta-learning/main.sh
# Executable = /shared/rsaas/miranda9/diversity-for-predictive-success-of-meta-learning/main.sh
SUBMIT_FILE = main.sh

# Output Files
Log          = $(SUBMIT_FILE).log$(CLUSTER)
Output       = $(SUBMIT_FILE).o$(CLUSTER)
# Error       = $(SUBMIT_FILE).o$(CLUSTER)
Error        = $(SUBMIT_FILE).e$(CLUSTER)

# Use this to make sure x gpu is available. The key words are case insensitive.
REquest_gpus = 1
requirements = (CUDADeviceName != "Tesla K40m")
# requirements = (CUDADeviceName != "Tesla K40m") && (CUDADeviceName != "NVIDIA A40")
# requirements = (CUDADeviceName == "Titan Xp")
# requirements = (CUDADeviceName == "Quadro RTX 6000")
# requirements = (CUDADeviceName == "NVIDIA A40")
requirements = (CUDADeviceName == "Quadro RTX 6000") || (CUDADeviceName == "NVIDIA A40")

# Request_cpus = 4
# Request_cpus = 8
# Request_cpus = 12
Request_cpus = 16
# Request_cpus = 40
# Request_cpus = 32

Notify_user = brando....@gmail.com
Notification = always

Environment = CONDOR_JOB_ID= $(CLUSTER)

# "Queue" means add the setup until this line to the queue (needs to be at the end of script).
Queue
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting output and error to the same file, e.g.

```
output = $(SUBMIT_FILE).o$(CLUSTER)
error  = $(SUBMIT_FILE).o$(CLUSTER)
```